# Does BugDroid only appear on Android version of JP:JR?

Tags: android, jetpack-joyride

When playing JetPack: Joyride on Android (**and *Nerd Repellent* is not active**) there are BugDroid ([Android mascot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Android_robot.svg) look-alike) characters walking around the laboratory and running away whenever they see my jetpack, just like ordinary scientists do. Since I don't play the game on other platforms, I was wondering: is Android the only version that contains its BugDroid mascot, as a homage to the Android Operating System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. I have never seen the BugDroid mascot on iOS, and I've played the game since iOS 4 (for reference, iOS 10 comes out in about a month).

Comment: Yeah, I know about iOS. Until Apple became so bad, it was one of my favorite OSes. Thanks, anyway

Comment: Apple would not allow such a thing either :D